# poly-time load balancing algorithm with a constant number of workload values

Tags: algorithm, np

The load-balancing problem is NP-hard. But what if there are only k different workload values, where k is a fixed constant?

For example, if k is 3, then any workload can be either s1, s2 or s3, where s1, s2 and s3 are arbitrary fixed number. In this case, is there a polynomial time load balancing algorithm with respect to n, which is the number of jobs?